# Combine where, or and clauses in sql request

Tags: sql

i want to set a filter for my product list so when the user set the shop name is shows only the products of that selected shop and when he also sets the Price limit it show the products of that same selected shop but with that desired price limit too

my sql request is like this but they told me it's wrong :

```
select nom from produit where boutique_id=3 or ( boutique_id=3 and Prix<500)
```

if there is any way i can do what i need to do please tell me

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Comment: it didn't work :/ it still works with the first condition only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select nom
from produit
where boutique_id = 3 and (Prix < ? or ? is null);
```

The `?` is the placeholder for your price parameter.

Comment: Prix < ? that's correct but also i want it to keep the same boutique_id

Comment: @Slim.aouadi That's what the code does.

Comment: @melpomene just for clearin in the ? i put the price limit or what ? i didn't understand the " or ? is null " for what

Comment: @melpomene i just tried that request but it's not what i really need i want to filter the product either with only the boutique_id or with the boutique_id and the price at same time

Comment: @Slim.aouadi That's what the code does.

Comment: @melpomene i am sorry but that's not correct it does not work as i want

Comment: @Slim.aouadi . . . Pass in the the price limit as a `NULL` value and it will work for you.

Comment: now it's better u should've told me this from the beggining :p thanks a lot !